# Can we add 2 icons in Navigation List (Not Custom)

Tags: android

Actually I have a navigation drawer with a simple item - icon (at left) and text (at right).
What I need to do is add a custom icon at runtime to the right of the text.
I have not used a custom navigation drawer I have used the default navigation drawer.
Please suggest if there is a way to do so. 
My Item is My Messages I want to add a round red drawable circle with text written on it.

[image: Current Image]

[image: Should look like this]

Answer (score 0):

Add items to your `strings.xml` file

```
<string-array name="navigation_drawer_items_array">
         <item>My Appointments</item>
         <item>My Messages</item>
</string-array>
```

Add to your String Arraylist

```
mNavigationDrawerItemTitles =
            MyApplication.getInstance().getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
```

Add item to your menu

```
mNavigationItemModel = arrayOfNulls<NavigationItemModel>(2)

            mNavigationItemModel[0] =
                NavigationItemModel(
                    R.mipmap.ic_appoinment,
                    MyApplication.getInstance().resources.getString(R.string.my_appoinments)
                )
            mNavigationItemModel[1] =
                NavigationItemModel(
                    R.mipmap.ic_message,
                    MyApplication.getInstance().resources.getString(R.string.my_messages)
                )
```

Comment: The above code will only add a single icon and a text
What I need is that the another icon should be added to the right of My Messages

Comment: Please check the 2nd image for your refference

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi you can set drawable right to your textview in adapter.

Comment: this is not a custom drawer this is the default

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to the item that needs another icon on the right

app:actionLayout="@layout/red_dot"